# XAMPP not updating "unsecure" to "secure" when I add a password for root

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, localhost

I have successfully added a username and password for "These XAMPP pages are no longer accessible by network for everyone" to be listed as secure, but no matter what I do for the MySQL "Password Changing", "The MySQL admin user root has NO password" and "PhpMyAdmin is free accessible by network" will not say "secure". Is there some kind of configuration I am missing?

I have started and stopped the XAMPP server immediately after, immediately after closing all browser windows, and immediately after killing the Chrome process. I have also tried this with Firefox.

Should I do some kind of re-install? I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the basic configuration of XAMPP, phpMyAdmin have public access.

You can change the MySQL root password and choose the authentication method for phpMyAdmin from the security console at `localhost/security/index.php`

Before you can access the MySQL server, phpMyAdmin will prompt you for a user name and password. Don't forget to set a password for the user "root" first.

The page should look like this:

[image]

After you set your password it should look like this (You have to restart your MySQL server):

(Page: `localhost/security/index.php`)

[image]

So now if you want to call `phpmyadmin` you should see this:

[image]

Comment: I would like to stress that, as I have outlined above, I have done this. It gives me a success message, and no matter what I do (combinations of restarting MySQL and the browser) the list does not update to "secure".

Comment: @MikeJannino see my update! Does you localhost look the same ? with the 2 secure?

Comment: I have done exactly as you've said before posting this question, the problem is that it does not update with both of them saying secure. "These XAMPP pages are no longer accessible by network for everyone" is the only secure one.

Comment: Come to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64278/xampp-not-updating-unsecure-to-secure-when-i-add-a-password-for-root
Also i don't understand what exactly your question is know!